# Controlling Ads in Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I have a libgdx game and I put admob ads to it

I control ads using the code in libgdx wiki to show ads only on game screen but wiki says " Note that this is probably not the best way to control AdMob" why is it ?

If it is not the best way what is the best way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably says that because hiding ads wasn't stop the fetching ads from server formerly. 
So when you hide ads it was still counting as impression but not bringing money and lower the average money earn (RPM).
But now when you hide ads it is no longer fetching ads so not worry about it now.